# string palindrome in c

Tags: c, string

I am writing a program of string pallindrome, code is compiling successfully but on running it accepting the string but nothing after that, the output window stays on hold with cursor blinking, help me what is wrong with this code. 
I am using dev-c++

```
    gets(ch); // the program stops here
    p=ch;

    while(ch!='\0')
    { p++;
        size++;
    }


    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(c[i]==c[j])
            printf("string is pallindrome");

        else printf("string is not pallindrome");
     }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using a C++ compiler, write C++ code! Your entire code uses only C semantics and types. There are far cleaner ways to do this using actual C++.

Comment: Step through your program line by line using a debugger, to find your bugs .

Comment: @CoryKramer  but i'm learning to program in c

Comment: @madara Then don't tag C++, only tag C. If you tag C++, you will get C++ answers. That is the point of tags.

Comment: @CoryKramer I fixed the tags for great justice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
    while(ch!='\0')
```

`ch` is a char array, and you are comparing it with a single `char`.

Also, `size` is not initialised.

I would suggest something like this:

```
size=0;
while(ch[size]!='\0')
   {    p++;
      size++;
   }
```

or, using the pointer method:

```
 while(*p!=0)
 {
      p++;
      size++;
 }
```

Also, instead of printing inside the `for loop` (which would make it print several times), use a flag variable.

Comment: then should i compare with a pointer?
while(p!='\0')
{p++;
size++;}

Comment: @madara: `while(*p!=0)` would work. But do initialise `size`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop, for example `while (i < i)`.
Look at this example that will do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* in c99 use <stdbool.h> instead*/
typedef int bool;
#define true 1;
#define false 0;

int main(void)
{
    char ch[20];

    puts("enter the string: ");
    gets(ch);

    size_t size = strlen(ch);

    bool pallindrome = true;
    int j = size-1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < j)
    {
        if(ch[i] != ch[j]) {
            pallindrome = false;
            break;
        }
        ++i;
        --j;
    }

    if (pallindrome)
        printf("\"%s\" is pallindrome\n", ch);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" is not pallindrome\n", ch);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @madara I edited my answer with an example